# Updating dirty raw contact

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I created a raw contact which is updated if there is any changes from the contact. Peradventure, the user deletes the raw contact before the next sync, the contact has a dirty flag.

From my implementation, in such scenerio, i first clear the flag and update the contact.

```
private static void clearDirtyFlag(Context context, long rawContactId,
                                   BatchOperation batchOperation) {
    final ContactOperations contactOp =
            ContactOperations.updateExistingContact(context, rawContactId,
                    batchOperation);

    final Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
    contactOp.updateDirtyFlag(false, uri);
}

private static void updateContact(Context context,
                                  ContentResolver resolver, String accountName, User user,
                                  long rawContactId, BatchOperation batchOperation) {
    Uri uri;
    String cellPhone = null;
    String otherPhone = null;
    String email = null;

    final Cursor c =
            resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, DataQuery.PROJECTION,
                    DataQuery.SELECTION,
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactId)}, null);
    final ContactOperations contactOp =
            ContactOperations.updateExistingContact(context, rawContactId,
                    batchOperation);

    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            final long id = c.getLong(DataQuery.COLUMN_ID);
            final String mimeType = c.getString(DataQuery.COLUMN_MIMETYPE);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Data.CONTENT_URI, id);

            if (mimeType.equals(StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                final String lastName =
                        c.getString(DataQuery.COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME);
                final String firstName =
                        c.getString(DataQuery.COLUMN_GIVEN_NAME);
                contactOp.updateName(uri, firstName, lastName, user
                        .getName());
            } else if (mimeType.equals(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                final int type = c.getInt(DataQuery.COLUMN_PHONE_TYPE);

                if (type == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    cellPhone = c.getString(DataQuery.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    contactOp.updatePhone(cellPhone, user.getCellPhone(),
                            uri);
                } else if (type == Phone.TYPE_OTHER) {
                    otherPhone = c.getString(DataQuery.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    contactOp.updatePhone(otherPhone, user.getCellPhone(),
                            uri);
                }
            } else if (Data.MIMETYPE.equals(Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                email = c.getString(DataQuery.COLUMN_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
                // contactOp.updateEmail(user.getEmail(), email, uri);

            }
        } // while
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }


}
```

issue is the contact is never updated as the raw_contact_id no longer exist.
Am I implementing this the right way or what way can I update a dirty raw contact. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only the SyncAdapter (the account application to which the raw contacts belongs to, eg Facebook, Google, Corporate) can access the deleted contacts. No other application will be able to access that raw contact as it has to be deleted by the sync adapter after deleting it on the server. If you are writing a sync adapter you have pass CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER in the URI.